# Force-sensitive resistors to measure impact

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am trying to utilize three FSR's to make a target that measures the impact force of a gel blaster that shoots water-based beads. The FSR's are connected to a 4-channel opamp and an ESP32 board and prints out the voltage 0 (no force) to 3.3 (max. force).

The issue I am running into however, I believe the impact happens at too fast of a rate for the sensors to catch. Right now I have the FSR's taped to a thin piece of plastic, with the idea that the impact of the bead would trigger the FSR's. They don't measure anything upon impact. I'm unsure if this is a sampling rate issue (measuring once every 1ms), or due to the physical capabilities of the FSR. I have attached the logic below.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
    pinMode(fsrPins[i], INPUT);
  }
  analogReadResolution(12);
}

void loop() {
  int totalForce = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    int rawValue = analogRead(fsrPins[i]);
    voltage = (rawValue *3.3)/4095.0;
    forces[i] = newtonConversion(voltage);
    totalForce += forces[i];
    delay(1);
  }
```

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas on how to complete this idea. Are there components better-suited for this task than FSRs?

Comment: remove all calculation code ... focus on one sensor ... read sensor value and if it's over a certain trigger value, then print value ... adjust trigger value and repeat if necessary  .... that will determine if the sensor is actually suitable

Comment: The water based beads may be too soft/compliant for your FSR.  Their impact probably doesn't generate a sharp, impulse like response.  Why don't you try some BBs and see what the results are.

Comment: Can you see any activity when you press slowly on the FSR??  Are you sure it's working *at all*?

Answer (score 1):

It's more likely that the Arduino is just missing a very short-lived event.

My easiest recommendation would be to pare your code down to bare minimum, as @jsotola recommends in his comment.

The best recommendation is until you know what your signal looks like, give up on trying to acquire it with a microcontroller at all, and use an oscilloscope with a manual trigger setting to try to capture the transient event.

Further-- these FSR's are not all that people believe them to be.  It can be pretty tough to use them in a way that's repeatable.